# Taking Over An Existing Web Project: How to Access the Yii WebApp?

Tags: web, yii, filezilla

I'm new and I just took over management of a website that runs on the Yii framework.

I have access to the cPanel, FTP and the web server. I can see the /var/www/yii/framework/ folder and everything inside- including the Yiic.php & Yiic.bat files on the FTP & public server via Filezilla.

I was told that the source codes are hosted on a private git server. But I read from the yii documentation that there is a webapp i can access where I can make core changes to the site.

**How can I access the Yii Webapp to make changes to the site? (All i see now are .php files on filezilla)**

Comment: You need to create application outside of framework folder. Did you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create application outside framework folder, then use framework in that  application. Look [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/start.testdrive) for some overview.